# DNameNode class from MSVC binaries

Tags: ida, windows, hexrays

I'm reversing some old game (for fun, to restore its priceless rules). It's been most probably linked statically to MSVCRT, some very old version. Also it uses heavily WinAPI (like ODCBC drivers, crypto libs, multi-threading and network stuff).
So far I found one very weird class:

```
DNameNode
```

What can I see from reversed code, it's a base class for some other structures, and it uses some synchronization constructions.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any info about those **DNameNode**s. Do you have any ideas, what's are they used for?

Guessed c.tor of some of (guessed) derived class:

```
DNameNode *__thiscall sub_4182BD(DNameNode *this)
{
  DNameNode *v1; // ST00_4@1

  v1 = this;
  DNameNode::DNameNode(this);
  *(_DWORD *)v1 = &off_45F538;
  *((_DWORD *)v1 + 3) = -1;
  *((_DWORD *)v1 + 2) = 0;
  return v1;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's something, related to name decoration:
http://read.pudn.com/downloads3/sourcecode/windows/248345/win2k/private/windbg64/langapi/undname/undname.cxx__.htm
So, it's kind of old implementation of Win RTTI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now I'm pretty sure, that it was FLIRT signature missmatch. **DNameNode** from my code doesn't have anything common with **undname** tool (which looks like IDA missmatches it with).

Also, I found in Google, that this structure is present in [WoW](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/347720-wow-4-3-4-15595-info-dump-thread.html), Diablo2 and Lineage clients.

So, it's a structure with 1 sizeof(ptr) field and 4 structures. In my case it was kind of smart pointer.